# Error-Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly While running creating docker image with wine and winetricks

Tags: docker, shell, ubuntu-18.04, wine

I want to try docker for one of my GUI application having .exe. I am trying to install wine and winetricks for the same.

Here is my Dockerfile,

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 
RUN apt-get update   
RUN apt-get install -y wget software-properties-common gnupg2 winbind xvfb   
RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386
RUN echo $DISPLAY
RUN yes Y |  apt-get remove wine* --purge
RUN yes Y |  apt-get remove winetricks* --purge
#wine 
RUN yes Y |  apt-get autoremove -y
RUN yes Y |  apt-get remove wine --purge
RUN yes Y |  apt-get remove --autoremove wine-*
RUN yes Y |  apt autoremove wine-devel wine-devel-amd64 wine-devel-i386 winehq-devel winetricks || :
RUN yes Y |  rm -r /home/etp/.wine/ || :
RUN yes Y |  apt-get autoclean

#install wine
RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386
RUN wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
RUN apt-key add winehq.key

RUN  apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
#RUN  apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 76F1A20FF987672F
RUN  apt-get update
RUN yes Y |  apt install winehq-stable=4.0~bionic  wine-stable=4.0~bionic  wine-stable-amd64=4.0~bionic  wine-stable-i386=4.0~bionic
RUN yes Y |   apt-get install libncurses5:i386 
#libncurses6:i386
#install winetricks
RUN mkdir -p /home/myproject
RUN yes Y |  apt-get install winetricks
RUN yes Y |  chown -R $USER: /home/myproject
RUN DISPLAY=:0 winetricks mdac28 **<<-- This generated a dialog box when I install without docker**
RUN DISPLAY=:0 winetricks jet40 **<<-- This generated a dialog box when I install without docker**
RUN DISPLAY=:0 winetricks native_mdac **<<-- This generated a dialog box when I install without docker**
RUN yes Y |  apt-get remove winbind
RUN yes Y |  apt-get install winbind
RUN WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=/home/myproject winecfg
RUN WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=/home/myproject winetricks native_mdac
RUN WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=/home/myproject winetricks mdac28
RUN WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=/home/myproject winetricks -q jet40
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["/root/startup.sh"]
```

The required dependencies which are **mdac28,jet40,native_mdac** generates dialog box which we need click on Next and install it. This works fine in without docker installation in Ubuntu 18.04. I want to replicate the same for inside docker as well and somehow make docker to create those popup to install those dependencies.

While running ,

```
sudo docker build .
```

I am getting following error,

```
0043:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0043:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
------------------------------------------------------
Note: command wine mdac_typ.exe returned status 43. Aborting.
------------------------------------------------------
The command '/bin/sh -c DISPLAY=:0 winetricks mdac28' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Is there any way to resolve this error ?

Comment: Getting GUI applications to work in a container at all is tricky and non-portable across operating systems.  In principle it might be possible to get `xvfb` running as a background process within a single `RUN` command if the dialog appears temporarily, but it'll still be hard to interact with it.  Using an OS emulator inside a container system seems like an unusual technology choice, could you use a native Windows VM or run WINE directly on the host instead?